# If value isn't any of the following XSLT

Tags: xslt, xpath

I'm trying to represent the following in an XSLT if:

```
if (status != Disconnected || status != BadNumber || status != NoCallsAccepted || status != Fax)
```

I know this can be done with a `choose` expression but i didn't want to add so much verbosity to the template...

I've tried different variations of the follow using both AND and OR when it appropriate:

```
<xsl:if test="not(@status = 'BadNumber') AND not(@status = 'Disconnected') AND not( @status =  'NoCallsAccepted') AND not(@status = 'Fax')">
```

But this leads to syntax errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This can be expressed in a more compact form as**:

```
<xsl:if test=
 "not(contains('|BadNumber|Disconnected|NoCallsAccepted|Fax|',
               concat('|', @status,'|')
               ))">
```

**In XPath 2.0 (XSLT 2.0) even a more compact expression is possible:**

```
<xsl:if test="not(@status=('BadNumber','Disconnected','NoCallsAccepted','Fax'))">
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured out my mistake... uppercase and.

```
<xsl:if test="@status != 'BadNumber' and @status != 'Disconnected' and @status !=  'NoCallsAccepted'and @status != 'Fax'">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using XSLT 2.0, you can simplify:

```
<xsl:if test="not(@status=('BadNumber','Disconnected','NoCallsAccepted','Fax'))">
```